# Как в OpenGL заполнить буфер GL_ARRAY_BUFFER одним числом?

Tags: opengl

Мне требуется в каждом кадре заполнять весь буфер (`GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`) одним числом типа `float`. Как это будет оптимальней всего сделать?

Comment: А можно узнать подробнее, зачем вам его заливать одним числом. Может быть проблему можно решить другим путём?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нет простого способа это сделать. Нужно через `glBufferData` или `glBufferSubData` (сначала создав массив из нужного числа, повторенного N раз), или через `glMapBuffer`. А вот что быстрее - нужно проверять...

Comment: @Unick я хотел сделать систему освещения и в буфере я хочу хранить 
расстояния координат вершин до источника света. и в начале каждого кадра заполнять буфер значениями максимальной дальности освещения .

Comment: А не получится считать это расстояние в вершинном шейдере?

Comment: А использвать этот буффер вы хотите в пиксельном шейдере? Или каким-то особым способом?

Comment: @Unick буфер должен был быть размером в количество лучей и в геометрическом шейдере находить точку падения лучей на ребро и если эта точка ближе чем предыдущия то заменять её в буфере.

Comment: Могу ошибатся, но может получится сначал запустить псевдо рендер (простой объект с простым шейдером), который только заполнит ваш буффер нужными занчениями, а потом уже нормальный рендер. Правда будет ли это быстрее чем glMapBuffer непонятно.

Comment: Ещё пришла идея с созданием двух GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, один из них хранит те значения что вам нужно (создаётся один раз и заполняется glMapBuffer ) и перед рендером просто копируете его значения в рабочий GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. Т.к. всё будет происходить на видеокарты может получится довольно быстро.